# How to write a deduction guide for passing anonymous std::array of variable size?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I want to be able to pass an anonymous `std::array` of variable size to a constructor:

```cpp
using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
struct A
{
    array<string, N> const value;
    A (array<string, N>&& v): value {v} {}
};
```

Trying to pass an anonymous array like this …

```
A a { { "hello", "there" } };
```

This results in the following error (using clang++):

> error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'A'

If I don’t use a template and specify the size of the array in the definition, it works:

```cpp
struct A
{
    array<string, 2> const value;
    A (array<string, 2>&& v): value {v} {}
};

A a { { "hello", "there" } };
```

Is it possible to write a deduction guide for this case? If so, how?
If not, how else could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on gcc 11 with `-std=c++17`:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
struct A
{
    array<string, N> const value;
    A (array<string, N>&& v): value {v} {}
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
A( T (&&) [N]) -> A<N>;

A a { { "hello", "there" } };
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/16dj97nqz)

Comment: Since OP wants an array of string, you can avoid deducing the `T` entirely https://godbolt.org/z/cb7rrj888

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.
Just one question: Why are the parentheses in `(&&)` necessary?

Comment: For the same reason why `int *f[4]` and `int (*f)[4]` are two completely different things. One is an array of four pointers to an integer, the other is a pointer to an array of four integers.